# Build fail success environment variable

Tags: scripting, continuous-integration, hudson

I was hoping to know if there is a way to run a particular script, if and only if the build is successful. So if the build fails the script doesn't run.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options.

- Easiest: you have a free-style software project -- just create an addition build step at the end of your build. The step will not be executed if one of your previous step fails. I don't know how it behaves if your build is unstable.
- Also easy: You have a Maven project: create a post build step (Steps to run after mvn build). You have the options to let these post build steps run on successful, successful + unstable, or always.
- Create another job for your script and trigger it with the [parametrized trigger plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). This plugin gives you the most flexibility.

Hope that helps.